# pip install gives error on webfaction

Tags: python, django, pip, webfaction

pip install mandrill

gives me following error

```
File "/home/rock/bin/pip", line 8, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/rock/lib/python2.4/pip-6.0.3-py2.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how do i fix this ?

( i am using `webfaction` . i needed to install `mandrill` . i installed pip using easy_install pip )

Comment: Only very few packages still support python2.4. You may want to install `python2.7`. I would suggest having a look at `pyenv`https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.

Answer (score 3):

found my way out (solution)

webfaction has a folder called webapps which contains the project within project there is a lib folder containing the python according the one you choose for installing django. there is another lib folder in home/username directory which contains older version of pythons also.
if you run easy_install pip from there it will have problems. go inside the python2.7 folder within webapps/yourproject/lib/ and then run `easy_install-2.7 pip`      . this solved the problem . then i could install mandrill using `pip install mandrill`

Comment: Small note: You don't have to `cd` into any special folder. Just `easy_install-2.7 pip` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Python version that is 10 years old and isn't supported anymore (2.4). The Mandrill package simply requires a more recent version of Python.

You probably should change hosts.

Comment: or maybe just install python2.7 locally :)

Comment: actually this is the configuration i have Django 1.5 (mod_wsgi 3.4/Python 2.7) , but i see that older versions of python also exists in lib folder so i think the error is related to the older version someway

Comment: @silverkid It looks like you might have symlinked the Python 2.4 `pip` at `/home/rock/bin/pip` (and `home/rock/bin/` is first on your `PATH` I assume). Can you post the `/home/rock/bin/pip` file in your question?

Comment: @cel Multiple versions of Python on the same box isn't always that easy to deal with so I wouldn't recommend it if you can avoid it. As it happens, it seems that having multiple Python versions is in fact the problem here.

Comment: how do i attach pip ? btw here is the listing of bin directory               cd bin/
[rock@web374 bin]$ ls
mandrill  pip  pip2  pip2.4  sendmail.mandrill

Comment: @silverkid Just run `cat /home/rock/bin/pip` and paste the output here. It shouldn't be more than a dozen lines long.

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/python2.4
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==6.0.3','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==6.0.3'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==6.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )

Comment: @silverkid As you can see from the first line (the "shebang line"), this uses Python 2.4. Did *you* create this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67970/discussion-between-silverkid-and-thomas-orozco).